# Magento 2 XML RPC / SOAP

Tags: php, magento

Does Magento 2 use the same XML/RPC API from Magento 1? I am trying to connect to example.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc, but I receive a 404 not found error.

Is there a .NET library for the Magento 2 REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the below article in magento 2 there is no longer an XML-RPC based API. I have also tried to connect through xml-rpc API. But there is no provision to create a user for xml-rpc as it was in Magento 1.

http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/142036931270/magento-2-understanding-the-web-api-architecture